# How do I turn a 4-variable k-map with don't cares into a simplified boolean expression?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

The trouble I'm having here is that I don't know a method (*well I do know I could do it the long way i.e w'x'y'z' + w'x'y'z . . .*) for turning this into a simplified boolean expression. I've done some searches on the web and looked at some YouTube videos: there was this one method here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYJNJIkiv80; however, I'm still confused by it.

[image]

**Update:** (I've used the method where variables are not counted if the columns/rows are different.)
[image]

**A big update to this: my solution even though it was correct was not the best solution: the professor did not like it, so when he went over this problem, he gave what should be the answer which in this case only has 4 literals:**

[image]

Comment: Looks good.  2/3 of the way there.  Missing corners.

Comment: oh yeah group (8,10), thx

Comment: Not (8,10) but (0,2,8,10)

Comment: ah, i get it now; i've updated the thread

Comment: It's not x dot not z in the last term.

Comment: spoiler alert: \$ \bar{w}\bar{x} + \bar{w}z + \bar{x}\bar{z} \$ is another solution but it can be simlplifgied further: \$ \bar{w}(\bar{x} +z )+ \bar{x}\bar{z} \$